# Propositional variables confusion

Tags: logic, self-learning, intuition

I was reading about mathematical logic when I read this.
[image: https://brilliant.org/practice/introduction-to-formal-logic/?chapter=formal-logic&p=1]

How $q\wedge r$ is determined to be just true?

Comment: No, we write a statement to *assert* that it is true.  Anyhow;  $q\wedge r$ is true if and only if both $q$ and $r$ are true.  So when we write $q\wedge r$ we mean that about $q$ and $r$.

Comment: See [Logical assertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_assertion): "In logic, logical assertion is a statement that asserts that a certain premise is true, and is useful for statements in proof." To mean this, it is sometimes used the [turnstile symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_(symbol)) : $\vdash$.